# Non blocking CORBA C++ server: how to avoid 100% CPU utilization?

Tags: c++, architecture, cpu-usage, corba

I'm developing a CORBA server in C++. For various reasons (mainly because I have other tasks to perform in the main thread), I'd like to use the non-bloking APIs `work_pending()` and `perform_work()`.

A trivial snippet of code would be:

```
while ( !shutdown )
{
    if ( orb -> work_pending() )
        orb -> perform_work();
    if ( <other_requests> ) // my queue of non-corba activities
        <process_request>;
}
```

However, this code uses the CPU at 100%.

I guess a 100% CPU utilization is not acceptable, not even in a [multicore] server (can you please confirm that?), so my solution to this issue is to improve the while cycle with a `sleep_until`:

```
while ( !shutdown )
{
    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();

    while ( orb -> work_pending() )
        orb -> perform_work();

    while ( <other_requests> )
        <process_request>;

    std::this_thread::sleep_until( now + milliseconds( 10 ) );
}
```

With this solution I can ensure a max response time of 10ms and a low CPU load when idle.
Of course I can tune the 10ms value to balance the two parameters.

My question are:

1. Is this a valid solution?
2. Is there a "standard" way to solve the 100% CPU issue in my case?

**NOTE**: I already know I can use the blocking `ORB::run()` + multithread, but my question is about the non blocking API `ORB::perform_work()`, so please don't waste time asking me why I want to use a single thread architecture and please don't propose alternatives to `ORB::perform_work()`. I'm just experimenting different architectures. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of sleep, what happens if you call `yield()`?

Comment: The second design has a potential flaw, if ``orb->work_pending()`` doesn’t become false for a long time (e.g. because of work being complex), other requests won’t be handled during that time. Also, ``sleep_for`` is easier to read than ``sleep_until`` in this case.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch unfortunately with `yield()` I get the same high CPU load.

Comment: It looks like the approach you are taking is to use what is called a polling loop to poll the service in order to see if there is work to do.  While there are certainly applications for polling loops they tend to have some undesirable characteristics such as 100% CPU utilization unless one uses measures like a `sleep()` or `yield()` or other measure to allow other threads and processes access to the CPU. One other suggestion would be to drop the thread priority if using `yield()`.  You may also need to drop the process priority.  You really should use a blocking or signal architecture.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I used `while` because I do want give priority to CORBA requests. I used `sleep_until` instead of `sleep_for` for the same reason.

Comment: What are your other tasks, and how are they provisioned?  Is there a signalling api with handles?

Comment: What's the problem with multiple threads?

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you use

```
CORBA::ORB::work_pending (ACE_Time_Value &tv)
```

instead?

I'm not sure if I understand the documentation correctly. But it looks like this waits for something to happen for at most **tv** seconds, and then returns. The advantage would be, compared to a sleep of 10ms, that if something happens in ORB during this 10 ms, you can immediately react, without any delay. Of course, if something happens in *other requests* you still have the delay of 10ms...

Comment: +1 The documentation is really abysmal, but you seem to have dug out the one good function. This is by far the preferrable way of implementing it.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it with TAO, use the work_pending/perform_work operations that take an ACE_Time_Value as argument for specifying the duration.

Comment: Unfortunately the function you suggest is not standard, but a proprietary extension you can only find in a specific ORB library (i.e. "TAO"). I'm afraid I cannot accept this as a valid answer. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, I see... too bad, I think that would have been a really nice solution :)

Comment: In this case, I think your solution is about as good as it gets without multiple threads. 100% CPU is not the way to go. But you might get away with quite a bit less than 10ms and still have the CPU almost idle, I would guess.

Comment: As far as I know, the standard case to solve this problem is to use "select" when waiting on multiple channels for input, without using any CPU. Thats whats implemented in TAO, as far as I could see in their reference source code.